# Unable to load local storage image in webview

Tags: android, webview

Unable to load image from local storage in webivew. I have gone through many answers in this forum most of them are telling it to do like this. But still image is not loading in imageview.

```
     val file = File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.pdftranslator/files/haga.jpg")
        if (file.exists()){
            Log.i(TAG, "File exis: ")
        }
     val wview = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
        wview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        wview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        val html = "<html><body> <img src=\"file://"+file.absolutePath+"\"/></body></html>"
        Log.i(TAG, "html "+html)
        wview.loadDataWithBaseURL("",html, "text/html", "utf-8","")
```

Comment: If not file exists then return. Dont continue as you do now.

Comment: file exist ...still no image is loading

Comment: Also use File.canRead() before continuing.

Comment: it is also true i checked

Comment: Try without the file://.

Comment: not worked.....